# jQuery Ajax Get result from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have this html form I need to get some result from the controller (like a Boolean result).
This is how my form looks like:

```
<div id="temp"></div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Result", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("str")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
}
```

This is how my Get Method and Post Method looks like in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string str)
{
   bool res = true;
   if(str == "Jude")
         res=true;
    Return View(res);
}
```

So now what I need to do is, I need to check whether the result is true or false and give a Confirmation to the user from the html page:

```
<script>
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        alert("hello");
        $.get("../Home/Index", function (data) {
            var res = html(data);
            if (res == true)
                $('#temp').replaceWith("Success");
            else
                $('#temp').replaceWith("Some Thing Went Wrong!!");                
        });

        //$.ajax({
        //    type: "GET",
        //    url: "../Home/Index",
        //    data: data,
        //    success: function (data)
        //    {
        //        $('#temp').append("hello");
        //    },
        //    dataType: dataType
        //});

    });
</script>
```

Please give me an idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return you data from controller as JSON, eg. your output should be like
{"res": true}

Then in js side:
...
if (data.res == true)
...